# Paypal IPN, We're sorry, but there's an HTTP error. Please try again

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a problem setting up PayPal IPN.
I tried with the IPN script from PayPal, but now I am trying my luck with this script [here](http://www.geekality.net/2011/05/28/php-tutorial-paypal-instant-payment-notification-ipn/)
I am testing everything with IPN Simulator from Paypal.

I assume that the problem is caused by this two lines:

```
 CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
 CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'cacert.pem',
```

If I set:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
```

The thing seemed to be working. I download the `cacert.pem` from [here](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)
I also tried with this:

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem',
```

And this

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\page\cacert.pem',
```

But it still does not working..I do not know how to debug curl, how to find what is going on..

With the IPN Script from PayPal that I got [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/ht_ipn/)
,I get the following error:

```
Error SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I am using PHP 5.3.8 and CURL version is 7.21.7 and is enabled.

**At the end I changed the host provider and the IPN Paypal is now working. I still don't know where was the problem because the code remained the same..I guess it was some PHP configuration problem.**

Comment: I am also getting this, did you manage to fix it?

Comment: And me! Is their whole service down? It appears to be sending data to my website (because the database table is updated) but the 'details' field is blank so it isn't receiving/sending information properly. If I post the information as here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#id08CKFJ00JYK then 'details' also appear in my database table. (I'm using Symfony2 Payum bundle)

Comment: At the end I changed the host provider and the IPN Paypal is now working. I still don't know where was the problem because the code remained the same..I guess it was some PHP configuration problem..